# MC33269ST-5.0T3 Voltage Regulator, does it exist?

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, schematics

I'm trying to implement an Arduino MEGA board into my PCB that I'm designing and I've come across a part on the schematic, MC33269ST-5.0T3.  I can't seem to find it anywhere, and it isn't on digikey.  The closest I can find is this here, but that is a 3.3 volt regulator: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/MC33269ST-3-3T3G/MC33269ST-3-3T3GOSCT-ND/2120818

Inspecting my Mega board that I have sitting on my desk it would appear to physically be the same package, and ON Semiconductor doesn't appear to make a 5V version in that type of casing, but I'm wondering if it is at all possible that it is a documentation error, or an obsolete part?

In any case, does anyone know where I can purchase this part, or an equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

It's shown in the Motorola [datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/motorola/MC33269D-5.0.pdf) so probably it just got dropped due to low demand.

It's not really a "low dropout" part, more of a medium dropout (1.2V).

Sourcing questions are off-topic here. You can look at the specifications and pick a similar part such as the ubiquitous LM1117-type parts eg. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Well from what i could find about the MEGA board it uses this component: "ON Semiconductor NCP1117ST50T3G" which looks to fit the component case you were looking for.

In any case, I would not be too worried about choosing another linear reg. they are for the most part quite up to the task. But if you wish to go down from a larger voltage (i.e. 12->5 V) then a large case (as this one) is highly recommended.